# Download the latest codecept.phar from a specific minor version

Tags: codeception

I have an update script to download some necessary tools like Codeception.

I knew, there are all version of codeception linked here http://codeception.com/builds

Is there a shortcut to get the latest codecept.phar from the minor version 2.0 or 2.1 and so on?

From, now I have to download it like: `wget http://codeception.com/releases/2.0.16/codecept.phar`

but i want to have something like `wget http://codeception.com/releases/2.0/current/codecept.phar`

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such feature.
Raise a feature request in https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues

Or use composer.